# Waiting time and turn around time in scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, computer-science, khan-academy

I constructed my gann-chart for all algorithms .
I recently found out that their is a new formula which can calculate waiting time and turn around time.

```
turnaround time= finishing time-arrival time
waiting time=turn around time-burst time
```

Does it valid for FCSF,SJF and round ..?

Comment: I think you meant "Gantt chart," rather than "gann-chart." Did you mean "First Come, First Served?" That would be FCFS. And I assume "round" is supposed to be "round-robin?" SJF is Shortest Job First? Do you have a reference for this "new formula" you discovered? Is there a particular reason you think that selection of the scheduling algorithm would affect how turnaround time and waiting time are calculated?

Comment: yes sir. you can google it . most of the sites referred to this formula ..

Comment: If most of the sites referred to this formula, it's not new.  Also, if you can Google the details, why ask here?

Comment: they didn't gave the explanation .

Comment: Edit your question and add a link to a site that refers to the formula you're using. If you want a clarification of something you've read, the least you can do is give me a link to text so that I can read it in context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Waiting Time and Turnaround Time in (non-preemptive) FCFS queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094558/calculating-waiting-time-and-turnaround-time-in-non-preemptive-fcfs-queue)