# Confusion with FCFS non-preemtive

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, scheduling

Good day,

I am a bit confused and hope it is the right place to clarify the question:

So I have the following processes arrival time(AT) and their service time (ST):

P1 AT=0, ST=25

P2 AT=1, ST=5

P3 AT=2, ST=4

If I analyse the way the average turnaround time is calculated by this: [Calculating Waiting Time and Turnaround Time in (non-preemptive) FCFS queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094558/calculating-waiting-time-and-turnaround-time-in-non-preemptive-fcfs-queue) the answer comes up to be 19.6(6) (If I understood it correctly) but if I look at this screenshot it is a different answer:

[image]

Which way is correct to calculate the average turnaround time? and how afterwards to calculate the average waiting time for this? As well how would you calculate if the first arrival time would be not 0. Please could you give examples and clear explanations.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that actually in the screenshot it has been the Average waiting time that has been calculated. And I did it completely wrong for the fallowing example the answers would be as fallows:

Average waiting time=0(as the first process does not wait) + (25-1 the process arrived 1 second later and started only at 25)+(30-2 the last process arrived 2 second later and started only at 30) = 52/3=17.3(3)

So basically waiting time for a single process = startTimeOfTheProcess - arrivalTime.

Average turnaround time is basically putting together the times how much each process run for so in this case it is: 25+29+32 =86/3=28.6(6)

Hope it will help somebody else as well.